# Scala: How to create a new list from the weighted difference of two lists added to a third

Tags: algorithm, list, scala, random

As part of an implementation of the [Differential Evolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_evolution) algorithm I need to implement the 'mutation' step:

1. Pick three members from the population at random, they must be distinct from each other as well as from a given member
2. **Calculate a donor member by adding the weighted difference of two of the vectors to the third**

[This](https://github.com/wilcoschoneveld/metaheuristics/blob/master/src/main/scala/metaheuristics/DifferentialEvolution.scala) is what I came up with:

```
// Algorithm types
type Member = List[Double]
type Generation = Vector[Member]

def mutate(index: Int, generation: Generation): Member = {
  // Create a random number stream with distinct values
  val selector = Stream.continually(Random.nextInt(N)).distinct

  // Select 3 mates from the generation
  val mates = selector.filter(_ != index).take(3).map(generation(_))

  // Calculate the donor member
  (mates(0), mates(1), mates(2)).zipped map {
    case (e1, e2, e3) => e1 + F * (e2 - e3)
  }
}
```

(I implemented the algorithm as explained [here](http://www.maths.uq.edu.au/MASCOS/Multi-Agent04/Fleetwood.pdf))

Now my question; Is there a better way to implement this step? I have been trying to find a better way to select 3 lists from a vector and zip them together but I couldn't find anything other then putting the selected lists in a tuple manually. The scala compiler gives a warning that instead of `mates(0)` one should use `mates.head`, which gives me an indication that this could be implemented in a more elegant way.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can `transpose` your `mates`, and than `map` over it with a `Seq` extractor:

```
mates.transpose map {
  case Seq(e1, e2, e3) => e1 + F * (e2 - e3)
}
```

This will be a `Stream[Double]`, so to get a `Member`, you'd have to call `toList` on it, or use `mates.toList.transpose ...`

Comment: Thanks! Awesome, I was hoping for something like this. Just a quick question, why are we allowed to use `Seq` to pattern match for `Stream`?

Comment: @Wilco `Seq` extractor works if its argument is any subclass of `Seq`, which `Stream` is. The extractor boils down to `def unapplySeq[A](x: Seq[A]): Option[Seq[A]] = Some(x)`, so it takes any subclass and then `unapplySeq` does the job to extract and check the elements.